# Regional Mathematics Olympiad(RMO-India) Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

How to do this problem? I drew the figure according to the given details but, I believe some extra lines should be drawn to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you know what Menelaus and Ceva Theorem are?

Comment: Yeah, sir but I just studied them yesterday so, didn't know in which type of questions to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying Menelaus to triangle $ADC$ and transversal $BPF$, we get

$$ \frac{AP}{PD} \times \frac{DB}{BC} \times \frac{CF}{FA} = 1, $$

or that $\frac{ AP}{PD} = 3$.

APplying Menelaus to triangle $AEC$ and tranvsersal $BQF$, we get

$$ \frac{AQ}{QE} \times \frac{EB}{BC} \times \frac{CF}{FA} = 1, $$

or that $\frac{AQ}{QE} = \frac{3}{2} $.

Now, apply Menelaus to triangle $APQ$ and transversal $BDE$ to obtain $ \frac{PB}{BQ}$.  You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Form the parallelogram $ABCG$ with centroid $F$, and write $BG=20a$. Comparing similar triangles $PAG$ and $PDB$ yields $BP=5a$ (and $PG=15a$). Likewise, comparing triangles $QAG$ and $QEB$ gives $BQ=8a$ (and $QG=12a$). Hence $PQ=BQ-BP=3a$ and so $BP/PQ=5/3$.

Answer (score -1):

The great thing about this is that it only says "triangle," so the answer is the same for all triangles. So why not take something that's very simple and suitable for the question - like an equilateral triangle with side length 3.

Consider the picture below:

[image]

For triangle ABP you know all angles and AB (length 3), so you can find BP by the law of sines. For triangle AQF you know all angles and AF (length 3/2), so you can find QF, also by the law of sines. The length of BF is $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}$ since ABF is a 30-60-90 triangle, so then you can find PQ by subtraction. Now you have all that you need!

Comment: But you proved that ratio for just one case. This is a contest problem so if you prove the ratio for just one specific case, you'll get just small amount of point, maybe $\frac{1}{5}$ of the total points, a situation that you don't want to happen. And if it's a high-level contest you surely end up with 0 points

Comment: @Stefan4024 yeah that's right.

Comment: My bad, I'm not familiar with the RMO-India question setup. Questions posed in this way in competitions I've gone to can be solved in this way.

Comment: It's not just about RMO, almost every contest in the world asks for a general solution, not just for a specific case.

Comment: Watch your assertions there, guy. I have zilch idea of what level your competition is at; there are competitions where this type of language is used to mask a simple problem, i.e. one where any specific situation simplifies to the general case.

Comment: You are right that the answer doesn't depend on which triangle you choose. But unfortunately, the angles at A are not all equal.

Answer (score -2):

Trisect the side of an equilateral triangle will not trisect the corresponding opposite angle. If so, we can trisect any given angle.